# delete whole BST in c

Tags: c, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I want to delete a whole BST to then fill it up again with other data.

This is my code:

```
struct node {
    char *value;
    struct node *p_left;
    struct node *p_right;
    int usable;
};

deleteTree(struct node* node){
    if (node == NULL) { return;}
    deleteTree(node->p_left);
    deleteTree(node->p_right);
    free(node);
}

main
//other things
deleteTree(tree1);
//fill tree2
//copy contents of tree2 into tree1 --> segfault
```

it doesn't seem to delete the tree but fill it up with strange values and if i try to use the tree again it gives me segmentation-fault. how can i fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "it doesn't seem to delete the tree", but the non-null value of `tree1` is no longer valid after the call `deleteTree(tree1)`, so trying to use the value of `tree1` (especially trying to dereference it) before assigning a new pointer value to it will result in *undefined behavior*. It may be less confusing for you if you assign `tree1 = NULL;` after the call `deleteTree(tree1);`.

Comment: You need to show us a [mcve]. What does _fill tree2_ and _copy contents of tree2 into tree1_ do? The problem is in that code you didn't show.